# Taxonomy vs Content Types or Entities

Tags: views, entities, taxonomy-terms

With all the power of D7 Views 3.x and modules like Node Reference and/or various entity reference modules, alongside flexibility of fieldable taxonomies, I have trouble deciding data structure scenarios for taxonomy vs content types. What are some use cases?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to check these 2 posts:

http://www.4sitestudios.com/blog/sep-13-2013/when-use-content-types-taxonomies-and-custom-entities-drupal

https://drupal.org/node/2075921

Comment: The 4sitestudios link is now http://www.4sitestudios.com/insight/when-use-content-types-taxonomies-and-custom-entities-drupal